# Converting List Array To Datatable in Java

Tags: java, cucumber

Can anyone suggest a solution please? I am trying to convert a list array to data table and pass it to another method, but it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the error:-

**cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Table is unbalanced: expected 0 column(s) but found 1.**

Sample code to explain the issue:-

```
public void test(){

 List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>();
        tabs.add("A");
        tabs.add("B");
        tabs.add("C");

        **DataTable allTabs = DataTable.create(tabs);
        receiveData(allTabs);**

}

public void **receiveData(DataTable data){**
 List<List<String>> tabs = tabs.asLists(String.class);
        for (int i = 1; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
            if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("A")) {
               System.out.println("Print A");

            }
            else if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("B")) {
                System.out.println("Print B");
            }
            else if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Print C");
            }
    }

*****************End of Issue*************************
```

*****Updated on 12/12/2019:-
    **Solution given by a  colleague below:-**

```
public void test(){

 List<String> tabs = receiveData("A", "B", "C");

        **DataTable allTabs = DataTable.create(tabs);
        receiveDataTwo(allTabs);**

}

**private List<List<String>> receiveData(String... tabs) {
        return Arrays.stream(tabs)
                .map(ImmutableList::of)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }**

public void **receiveDataTwo(DataTable data){**
 List<List<String>> tabs = tabs.asLists(String.class);
        for (int i = 1; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
            if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("A")) {
               System.out.println("Print A");

            }
            else if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("B")) {
                System.out.println("Print B");
            }
            else if (tabs.get(i).get(0).contains("C")) {
                System.out.println("Print C");
        }
}*****
```

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Answer (score -2):

for (int i = 1; i < tabs.size(); i++) {  ===> i=0
tabs's start is  0 ,or not 1.

Comment: I would like you to look at what you have done here again. Consider you are viewing it from someone else's viewpoint and tell me what you think?

Comment: I have been given a solution(You can see it in my original post- updated) by a colleague  and it works, but it would be interesting to know if there was a better one...@GerhardBarnard. I just wanted to convert a list array to datatable, that's it